# Is there any way to return the number I have guessed correctly and adding text behind it?

Tags: python, error-handling

Everything works fine until to the 2nd last line. I can't find a way to return the number I have guessed within a nice ending sentence.

Tried to convert return UserInput+" was the correct number into a whole int like return int(UserInput+" was the correct number.) - But that seems even more wrong. Lol`enter code here`

```
from random import randint

def Guess(n):
    Number=randint(0,n)
    UserInput=int(input("Insert your number here:"))
    while UserInput != randint:
        if UserInput<Number:
            print ("Your number is too small")
        if UserInput>Number:
            print ("Your number is too big")
        if UserInput==Number:
            return UserInput+" was the correct number.
        UserInput=int(input("Insert your number here:"))
```

I expect after guessing the correct number to be like : (int) was the correct number

Comment: print the sentence, return the number. two separate jobs. also, printing means either you typecast to string if you're trying to join them, or use commas `print(2, "some string")` or best, use a string format method such as f-strings `print(f" {some_variable} was the correct number")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should conver the int to string to return or print it
converting using str()

here is your code:

```
from random import randint

def Guess(n):
    Number=randint(0,n)
    UserInput=int(input("Insert your number here:"))
    while UserInput != randint:
        if UserInput<Number:
            print ("Your number is too small")
        if UserInput>Number:
            print ("Your number is too big")
        if UserInput==Number:
            print( str(UserInput)+" was the correct number.")
            break
        UserInput=int(input("Insert your number here:"))
```

Comment: Now it is adding : ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-17e1a4bc0a23> in <module>()
----> 1 Guess(33)

<ipython-input-2-4af6c68c6453> in Guess(n)
     11         if UserInput==Number:
     12             return UserInput," was the correct number"
---> 13         UserInput=int(input("Insert your number here:"))
     14 
     15 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: try to do `from random import randint` if it gives error thats mean the problem is from the random library

Comment: Nevermin it worked now. I restarted my kernel and everything works fine. Thank you for the quick help!

Comment: if the answer helps you, you can mark it as accepted and upvote it to show your appreciation. It also gives you both some rep. @DravenMain

Comment: You are welcome , 
give my answer the acceptance sign if it helps you :)